# i can not access the post in custom template of my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i added following code to use custom template for my recipes single page

```
function override_single_template( $single_template ){
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "recipes"){
        $single_template  = plugins_url('/recipe-single-page-template.php',__FILE__);
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'override_single_template',10);
```

and in my template i added following code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: recipe-single-page-template
Template Post Type: recipes
*/
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php echo $post->ID?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but i do not access the post and echo out post id will cuses the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

var dump $post outputs null

```
NULL
```

and following code will print out my custom template address

```
$current_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $current_url;
```

top code result:

```
https://charter.test/wp-content/plugins/recipe-plugin/templates/single-recipes.php
```

now whate should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to redirect a custom post type called recipes to a custom template? You don't need to override, by default wordpress has a built in dynamic content display system.

In your case, upon displaying a recipe it will search first for `single-recipe.php`, if not found, fallback on `single.php`, if not found, fallback on `404.php` and finally on `index.php`

You just have to create a file called `single-recipe.php`.

Your second problem is that there is no loop displayed in your file, you have to tell to wordpress that if a post exist, it should retrieve it and present it to you. For that we use the loop system.

Your `single-recipe.php` file should look like something like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Get theme header
*/
get_header();

/**
* Start loop
*/
if ( have_posts() ):
while ( have_posts() ):
the_post();

/**
* If we find a post, output the tilte
*/
echo the_title().'<br/>';

/**
* End loop
*/
endwhile; 
endif;

/**
* Get theme footer
*/
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answare. it does not work for me. i am trying to add my custom template from plugin and not from them folder. i added your code in my template file and it showed nothig